# UIWebview Does NOT complete Load page with "page NOT found" error when URL does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, webview

In my iphone app I've got to load a mobile website to a webview (that contain in a separate viewcontroller). All good and working fine.

I need to exit from webview when reach to specific set of URL's. The problem is some of these url's does not exis and therefore page does not finish load (Even with page not found error message to detect current url. Just hangs)

Would like to know if I have to enable any setting in the webView to allow load pages that does not really exist (With page not found error).

**OR**

Is this possible to know which URL going to load next in
**func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView)**

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
 {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myWebview.delegate = self

    var returnUrlAppendedPaymmentLink = "www.existing_url.com"
    let requestURL = NSURL(string: returnUrlAppendedPaymmentLink)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

    myWebview.loadRequest(request)
 }

 func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView)
 {
    var currentUrl = webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString ?? ""
    if (currentUrl == "www.special_url.com")
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
 }
```

Comment: this method: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To intercept specific URLs, use the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate method of `UIWebView`.

You can check the URL of the request in this method to see if this is your "special" URL, do your handling for this case and return `false` so the web-view won't load it.